# Absinthe returns an array that contains one null value instead of an empty array

Tags: graphql, elixir, apollo, vue-apollo, absinthe

I am confused by this behavior that I'm seeing with Absinthe.

For a top-level field, e.g.

```
    field :projects, list_of(:project) do
      arg :user_id, :string

      resolve(&ProjectResolver.list_projects/2)
    end
```

If `ProjectResolver.list_projects/2` returns `{:ok, []}`, then the JSON result will correctly be

```
{
  "data": {
    "projects": []
  }
}
```

However, for a subfield, e.g. the `tags` field in

```
  object :task do
    field :id, :string
    # ... Other fields

    field :tags, list_of(:tag) do
      resolve(&TaskResolver.list_tags/3)
    end

    # ... Other subfields
  end
```

If `TaskResolver.list_tags/3` returns `{:ok, []}`, I get

```
{
  "data": {
    "task": {
      "id": "ba156cde-8c5f-4806-b161-62071b0098b3",
      "tags": [
        null
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

instead of

```
{
  "data": {
    "task": {
      "id": "ba156cde-8c5f-4806-b161-62071b0098b3",
      "tags": []
    }
  }
}
```

which I think should be the reasonable response.

Now the non-empty array that contains one item (`null`) is causing headaches for me on the frontend (apollo), and I'm not sure if there's any way I can easily work around that. It would be ideal if the data returned is an empty array in the first place, and I don't see why it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immediately after posting this question I realized that it might well be that my resolver was not returning `{:ok, []}` after all... Indeed, it was returning `{:ok [nil]}` due to the Ecto query being wrong (`:left_join` instead of `:join`). That's why the returned JSON contains `[null]`. I just needed to fix my resolver function to actually return `{:ok, []}` in this case. I guess writing about an issue does help clear your thoughts on it.

Comment: "I guess writing about an issue does help clear your thoughts on it.": [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: @M.Justin M.Justin Yep

Comment: I would also consider making that field a `non_null(list_of(non_null(:project)))` to make the schema even more typesafe